# How does Spider-Man defy the rules of gravity and structural engineering?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

Throughout the movies, cartoons, comics and tv series Spider-Man is shown walking on, hanging from and swinging from all sorts of structures, surfaces, ceilings and walls.

I understand how he does this but what I don't understand is how structures that where never built to take the weight of a full grown human don't ever suffer. I once watched a plaster boarded ceiling fall off from the weight of a light being hung from it (rather then being fixed to the beam like it should have been).

Has this ever been addressed in any medium, has Spider-Man ever gone to land on something, or hang from a ledge that couldn't physically take his weight and then fallen? Has he ever crawled across an office ceiling only to find that polystyrene tiles held on a thin aluminum frame really isn't designed to take a humans weight?

Comment: You kind of answered your own question there. "movies, cartoons, comics and tv series". It's make-believe for kids and not real

Comment: His spider-sense tells him what's safe and what isn't

Comment: In universe, I think Valorum has nailed it.

Comment: I've encountered a couple of instances where his web wasn't sufficiently well-anchored. This is pretty answerable.

Comment: Same way [every other superhero does](https://www.amazon.com/Physics-Superheroes-Villains-Science-Spectacular/dp/1592405088)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't speak to Spider-Man's superhuman (and otherwise baffling) lightness, but I can certainly think of some examples where his judgement about the strength of the objects he's webbing onto has been lacking.

In the [latest Spider-Man outing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Homecoming), Peter tries to swing through the trees like a latter day Tarzan, with limited success.

[image]

and in [Spider-Man 2 (2004)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_2) he accidentally pulls the side off of two separate buildings.

[image]

This frame from [Essential The Amazing Spider-Man #001](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Essential-Spider-Man-TPB-Stan-Lee/dp/0785121927) would suggest that he's not always successful at *landing on things* either.

[image]

These panels from [Spider-Man - Matters of Life and Death #004](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785151036) would strongly suggest that his spider-sense (which he's lost following an accident) are what gives him the ability to identify strong spots to web onto.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou this is what I was looking for any evidence of Spidey either mis landing, or falling because things gave way, or a reason why he always landed. Looks like it is mainly his Spidey Sense